# Autofac integration with WCF : Passing BeginLifetimeScope() instead of Container

Tags: wcf, memory-leaks, autofac, factory-pattern, servicehost

currently in my application code is written like below and we are facing the memory leak issues

Here the container is holding all the layers object and not relasing them.

```
var container = builder.Build()
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(mainInterface, container);
```

Instead of this can i write like, is it recommended

```
var container = builder.Build()
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(mainInterface,container.BeginLifetimeScope()());
```

Comment: @R J: You haven't indicated your question?

Comment: Thanks for answering CharithJ. I just want to know that On autofac website it is writtent over there that For WCF Integration with autofac the following code needs to be written. var container = builder.Build()
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(mainInterface, container); instead of container can i pass the container.BeginLifetimeScope()?

Comment: @R J: Are both/any approaches works for you? What ever works for you should be fine I guess (not too sure). In terms of memory leak, make sure you Dispose the LifetimeScope .

Answer (score 1):

When ever you begin a new LifetimeScope, remember to dispose it once you finish with it. During the LifetimeScope dispose, Autofac disposes all the IDisposable instances it has created.